# IIS ARR and FastCGI: "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi, arr

I have an IIS/Windows 2008 setup with a hardware load balancer routing traffic to site A, which uses ARR to act as a reverse proxy for site B.  Site B also runs PHP via FastCGI.

The problem is that I sometimes see 500 errors in the IIS logs.  The failed request trace for site B shows this little gem (that I've been banging my head against the wall at for a couple of days):

> GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END BytesReceived="1", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.  (0x0)"
>
> GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY Buffer="_"

**Screenshot:** http://s29.postimg.org/esbkcead3/iis500.png

In contrast, this is what a normal request looks like:

> GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END BytesReceived="3702", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
>    (0x0)"
>    GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY Buffer=".........{{actual data; omitted}}.........."

So it looks like FastCGI is getting a corrupted buffer, and I'm not quite sure how that happens.  I would really appreciate it if someone can provide some suggestions.

Thanks!

(I *think* it does not occur when bypassing ARR, but it doesnt seem deterministic so I can't be sure given the limited testing due to the circumstances.  Disabling ARR is not an option anyway.)